# How to compute the PDF of a conditional distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, truncated-distributions

Let $T \sim Unif(0, 1)$. Then, $f_T(t) = 1 \text{ for } t \text{ in [0, 1] (0 elsewhere)}$.

**How do we formally compute $f_{T \mid T > 0.5}$?**

Intuitively, $f_{T \mid T > 0.5}(t) = 2 \text{ for } t \text{ in [0.5, 1] (0 elsewhere)}$, because we know that $\int_{0.5}^1 f_{T \mid T > 0.5}(t)dt$ must be 1, because T can't be greater than 1, and we are given that T is greater than 0.5, and so T must be between 0.5 and 1. Thus, the integral of the PDF over that range must add up to 1. In addition, we also know that $T \sim Unif(0, 1)$, which is just a flat line. Thus, it makes sense that $f_{T \mid T > 0.5}$ must also be a flat line. The only flat line that integrates to 1 over the range of 0.5 to 1 is $f_{T \mid T > 0.5}(t) = 2$.

This distribution is simple enough that I can just figure this out in my head. However, I'm struggling to figure out the formal math behind how to do this in general.

For example, how would you compute $f_{X \mid X > 1}(x)$ if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$? I can't as easily reason about the normal distribution as I can about the uniform distribution, so I do not know how to approach this.

**In general, how do you compute the PDF of a conditional distribution?**

Comment: Consider how much of the density you discard when you condition. Since the conditional PDF must integrate to $1$, how would you use that to adjust your conditional PDF?

Comment: Do you always multiply by some constant to rescale? If so, what is the name of the formal rule for doing that?

Comment: @ProQ Bayes' rule.

Comment: You describe *truncated* distributions. At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525918/919 I posted a general, formal account of truncation, including a derivation of the CDF and PDF of a truncated distribution.  The specific case of a truncated Normal distribution is treated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166273 (univariate) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158008/919 (multivariate).

Comment: Thank you! The [Wikipedia page for truncated distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) contained the answer I needed. In general, you always multiply the previous PDF by a constant $\frac{1}{F(b) - F(a)}$, where $F$ is the CDF for the function. For the uniform distribution, $F(x) = x$, so $F(1) = 1$ and $F(0.5) = 0.5$ and the PDF is $f(x) = 1$. So, the new PDF of the truncated function is indeed $\frac{1}{F(b) - F(a)} f(x) = (2) * (1) = 2$ over the range, and $0$ otherwise. (Since this question was marked as a duplicate, I cannot post this as an answer.)

Comment: Re "always multiply:" only in the special case of truncation in the tails.  (This is commonest.)